# Can supplementary materials be used in different manuscripts?

Tags: publications, supporting-information

Can the same supplementary materials be used in different manuscripts?

For example, hdy201491x2.docx in 
[this article](http://www.nature.com/hdy/journal/v114/n5/full/hdy201491a.html)
contains a table showing "Detailed hit frequencies (%) of the in silico analysis of the F479/R888 primer set for Bacteria, Archaea, and Eukaryota."

The same table appears as
mbt212162-sup-0002-tables1.docx in [this other article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1751-7915.12162/abstract).

Comment: Depends very much on the answer to [Do journals have legal copyrights to the online supplemental information?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65135/do-journals-have-legal-copyrights-to-the-online-supplemental-information)... which currently has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of originality, I would say that supplementary materials can be used in different manuscripts.

Indeed, supplementary materials is usually brought along the article/chapter to present a data set, as in your example, so it's like archival material, rather than its analysis/interpretation that is carried out in the article itself.

As a result, the same set of supplementary materials might be reproduced and used in different articles, but analysed in different and bringing to different conclusions.